# python 3 numpy save multiple arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have 3 arrays and one list:

```
array1.shape = (1000,5,5,7)
array2.shape = (1000,)
array3.shape = (1000,)
len(list1) =   (1000)
```

I want to save all of these to a numpy file. When I used to run in Python 2.7, the command I used to use was:

```
np.save(filename,[array1, array2, array3, list1])
```

And everything worked great, including loading all of the data with np.load. However, when I try this command in Python 3.6 I get an error:

```
could not broadcast input array from shape (1000,5,5,7) into shape (1000)
```

How am I able to save the 3 arrays as well as the list into a single numpy array in Python 3.6?

Comment: `np.save` makes one array from the input list, and saves that.  What does `np.array([array1, array2, array3, list])` do?  `np.savez` is designed to save multiple arrays without combining them into one.